# The socket connection was aborted

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service, that is hosted as a windows service, called by clients via proxy classes. The method in the proxy class looks like this:

```
    public CustomerResponse GetCustomers(CustomerRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            return Channel.GetCustomers(request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

GetCustomer presently returns me about 1000 records from my database. The problem is this:

1. I have ran my program on 4 different PCs, I'm only getting this error on 2 of them. The other 2 are fine, all with the same settings
2. On the 2 PCs with this problem, when I lowered the number of customer records in my database from 1000 to 200, the problem is resolved.
3. I have already max out all the settings that I know of in the config file

This is the exception message

The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9863281'.

I'm very certain it's not a time out issue as the exception is returned in less than a second.

This is my config file on the server

```
<services>
  <service name="CustomerService" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="CommonService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customTcpBinding"
      contract="ICustomerService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>       
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8542/CustomerService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DefaultBehaviour">

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And this is the config file on the MVC project

```
<bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="customTcpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="None"/>
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8542/CustomerService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="customTcpBinding" contract="ICustomerService" name="NetTcpBinding_CustomerService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
    </endpoint>
```

Comment: What is the lifecycle of the channel in question? I noticed that its a TCP binding, which could in theory be kept open. But .net reserves the right to close down a TCP connection if it is kept open between requests too long. I noticed that you haven't increased the between calls timeout.

Comment: No, I do not need anything more than 1 min for each call

Comment: I have also mentioned in my post that I get the error in less than a second. And 2 out of the 4 PCs I've tested this on works fine.

Comment: What about BETWEEN calls? It really looks like you are keeping your proxies around too long. Unless you are making 1000 DIFFERENT requests at the same time...

Comment: Hello, each call creates a new instance of the service. my WCF service is PerCall. Each request by the client creates a new instance of the channel

Comment: Also, mentioned in my OP, when I reduce the number of records in my DB. It works

Comment: Are you using callbacks?

Comment: No, I'm not using callbacks

Comment: okay...sounds like its not due to the timeout between proxy calls. I had noted the part about the number of records. But what I was trying to work out is if you tight loop GetCustomers and if not, what does CustomerRequest contain (ie does it grow with the size of the database). Simply put, from your code I can't tell what grows with your database, number of in flight calls or individual call payload size.

Comment: "socket timeout was '00:00:59.9863281'" and " I do not need anything more than 1 min for each call" seem to contradict

Comment: Precisely, which is what puzzles me

Comment: Small FYI: Don't ever do `try {} catch (Exception ex) {throw ex;}`. All that does is screw up your stack trace. If you must do something in the catch block, then throw the same exception again, then use `catch (Exception ex) { /* do something, then */ throw; }`

Comment: Please learn how to enable WCF tracing, and then learn about the timeout values (at least 4 types). Then you can go back and post more information about the issue, or you might have successfully resolved it on your own.